# JSON and callback in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, mamp

This is my PHP page, index.php in a localhost subfolder called testradio1:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tfmradio.co.uk/layout/widget/LargeScheduleWidget/css/styles.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var doFades = true;

var BauerStations = {
    Schedule : {}
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    BauerStations.Schedule.days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

    BauerStations.Schedule.Show = function () {
        _s = null;
        _startDate = null;
        _endDate = null;
        this.days = BauerStations.Schedule.days;
        _selector = '';

        this.setShow = function(s) {
            this._s = s;

            this._startDate = new Date( parseInt(s.startminutes, 10) * 1000);
            this._endDate = new Date(parseInt(s.endminutes, 10) * 1000 ); 

        };

        this.getEndDate = function(){
            return this._endDate;
        }

        this.getStartDate = function(){ 
            return this._startDate;
        }

        this._getShowDay = function (){
            return this.days[this.getStartDate().getDay()];
        };

        this._getShowUnitsTaken = function(){
            // if it's the same day
            return this._getEndUnits() - this._getStartUnits();
        };

        this._getEndUnits = function(){     
            if(this.getEndDate().getHours() == 0)
            {
                //console.log(this._s.longname  +' ends at midnight');
                return 48;
            }

            return this.getEndDate().getMinutes() !== 0 ? (this.getEndDate().getHours() * 2) : (this.getEndDate().getHours() * 2);
        };

        this._getStartUnits = function(){
            if(this.getStartDate().getHours() == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return this.getStartDate().getMinutes() !== 0 ? (this.getStartDate().getHours() * 2) : (this.getStartDate().getHours() * 2);
        };

        this.getCellPositions = function() {
            return {
                'start' : this.getStartDate(),
                'end'   : this.getEndDate(),
                'colIndex' : this.getStartDate().getDay() + 2,
                'startUnits' : this._getStartUnits(),
                'endUnits' : this._getEndUnits(),
                'unitsTaken' : this._getShowUnitsTaken()
            }
        };

        this.pad = function(number){
            return number < 10 ? '0'+number : number; 
        };

        // return the table cell html.
        this.toHtml = function () {

            var d = new Date();
            var units = this._getStartUnits();

            var rowspan = this._getShowUnitsTaken();        
            var desc = this._s.description;
            var name = this._s.longname;

            var starttime   = this.pad(this.getStartDate().getHours()) + ':' + this.pad(this.getStartDate().getMinutes());
            var endtime     = this.pad(this.getEndDate().getHours()) + ':' + this.pad(this.getEndDate().getMinutes());

            var site = this._s.websitelink;

            var cls = this.isActive() ? 'current-program' : '';

            var isToday = this.getStartDate().getDay() === d.getDay() ? 'active-program' : '';

            var html = '<td class="schedule-show ' + isToday + ' ' + cls + '" rowspan="' + rowspan + '" data-start="' + this.getStartDate() + '" data-end="' + this.getEndDate() + '">';
                html += '<div>';
                html += '<a href="' + site + '" title="' + desc + '">' + name + '</a>';
                html += '</div>';
                if(doFades)
                {
                    html += '<div class="schedule_details clearfix" style="display:none;">';
                    html += '<img width="105px" height="105px" alt="' + desc + '" src="' + this._s.showimage + '">';
                    html += '<strong>' + name + '</strong>';
                    html += '<p>' + desc + '</p>';
                    html += '<span>' + starttime + ' - ' + endtime +'</span>';
                    html += '</div>';
                }
                html += '</td>';            

            return html;
        };

        this.setTableSelector = function(sel){
            this._selector = sel;
        };

        // check if we should add the active class.
        this.isActive = function(){
            var t = new Date();

            return  t >= this.getStartDate() && t <= this.getEndDate();
        };
    };

    BauerStations.Schedule.ScheduleGen = function(){

        return {
            insertShow : function(show) {
                var p = show.getCellPositions();

                $('tr#units-' + p.startUnits).append(show.toHtml());
            },

            init : function (stationName){
                var self = this;

                // load the schedule.
                $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1/radio1/schedule.php?callback=?', {
                    name: 'MyStation'
                }, function(json){
                    // loop each show and append to our giant table.
                    // this is well sick.

                    if(json.success === false)
                    {
                        $('.content-inner table').remove();

                        $('<div>errors</div>').appendTo('.content-inner');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var currentDay = '';
                        var day = 0;
                        // highlight the current time..
                        var d = new Date();
                        var weekStart = new Date();

                        weekStart.setDate(d.getDate()-6-(d.getDay()||7));

                        $.each(json.data.schedule, function(i, broadcast){


                            var dStart = new Date( parseInt(broadcast.startminutes, 10) * 1000);
                            var dEnd = new Date(parseInt(broadcast.endminutes, 10) * 1000 ); 


                            /*// transform to a show object defined above, if the show spans 2 days we create two show objects.
                            // IF THE SHOW STARTS/ENDS AT MIDNIGHT, DON'T SPLIT IT.
                            if(dStart.getHours() !== 0 && dEnd.getHours() !== 0 && dStart.getDate() != dEnd.getDate())
                            {
                                var showOne = new BauerStations.Schedule.Show();
                                showOne.setShow(broadcast);

                                // set to midnight 
                                showOne.getEndDate().setHours(0);
                                showOne.getEndDate().setMinutes(dStart.getMinutes());


                                // append first half of show.
                                self.insertShow(showOne);

                                // handle second half.
                                var showTwo = new BauerStations.Schedule.Show();
                                showTwo.setShow(broadcast);

                                showTwo.getStartDate().setDate(showTwo.getStartDate().getDate() + 1);
                                showTwo.getStartDate().setHours(0);
                                showTwo.getStartDate().setMinutes(dEnd.getMinutes());

                                //console.log('2nd Half Start: ' + showTwo.getStartDate());
                                //console.log('2nd Half End: ' + showTwo.getEndDate());

                                self.insertShow(showTwo);


                            }
                            else
                            {*/
                                var show = new BauerStations.Schedule.Show();

                                show.setShow(broadcast);
                                show.setTableSelector('table#schedule');

                                // add the show to the table. Thankfully the order these come out the API means they get added 
                                // in the right place. So don't change the schedule builder code!

                                self.insertShow(show);
                            //}


                        });

                        var days = BauerStations.Schedule.days;     

                        // apply the current day / time classes 
                        $('th:contains('+ days[d.getDay()]+')').addClass('active');

                        $('td.time').each(function(i, cell){
                            // get the value, convert to int. 
                            var hours = $(cell).html().split(':')[0];

                            // compare the hours with now, add class if matched. 
                            if(parseInt(hours, 10) === d.getHours())
                            {
                                $(cell).addClass('current_time');
                            }
                        });
                    }


                    if(doFades)
                    {
                        // apply events to show info fade in / out.
                        $('td.schedule-show').hover(function(){
                            $(this).find('.schedule_details').fadeIn('fast');
                        }, function(){
                            $(this).find('.schedule_details').fadeOut('fast');
                        });
                    }
                });


            }
        };
    }();


    BauerStations.Schedule.ScheduleGen.init();

});
</script>

<!-- ============================================= END Navigation =============================================-->          

          <div class="content-inner">
                                              <div class="row">
          <div class="column size-10">
          <div class="large-schedule-widget main-col main-col-large widgetbox">
                     <table class="schedule-table">
                <!-- column headers -->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hide">Units</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                        <th>Monday</th>
                        <th>Tuesday</th>
                        <th>Wednesday</th>
                        <th>Thursday</th>
                        <th>Friday</th>
                        <th>Saturday</th>
                        <th>Sunday</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr id="units-0">
                        <td class="hide">0</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">00:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->

                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="units-1">
                        <td class="hide">1</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                    </tr>

                    <!-- echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    <tr id="units-2">
                        <td class="hide">2</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">01:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->

                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-3">
                        <td class="hide">3</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->                 
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-4">
                        <td class="hide">4</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">02:00</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-5">
                        <td class="hide">5</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->

                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-6">
                        <td class="hide">6</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">03:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-7">
                        <td class="hide">7</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-8">
                        <td class="hide">8</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">04:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-9">
                        <td class="hide">9</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-10">
                        <td class="hide">10</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">05:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-11">
                        <td class="hide">11</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-12">
                        <td class="hide">12</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">06:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-13">
                        <td class="hide">13</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-14">
                        <td class="hide">14</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">07:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                    <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-15">
                        <td class="hide">15</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-16">
                        <td class="hide">16</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">08:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-17">
                        <td class="hide">17</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-18">
                        <td class="hide">18</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">09:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-19">
                        <td class="hide">19</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-20">
                        <td class="hide">20</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">10:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-21">
                        <td class="hide">21</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-22">
                        <td class="hide">22</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">11:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-23">
                        <td class="hide">23</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-24"> 
                        <td class="hide">24</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">12:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-25">
                        <td class="hide">25</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-26">
                        <td class="hide">26</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">13:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-27">
                        <td class="hide">27</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-28">
                        <td class="hide">28</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">14:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-29">
                        <td class="hide">29</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-30">
                        <td class="hide">30</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">15:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-31">
                        <td class="hide">31</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-32">
                        <td class="hide">32</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">16:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-33">
                        <td class="hide">33</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-34">
                        <td class="hide">34</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">17:00</td> 
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-35">
                        <td class="hide">35</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-36">
                        <td class="hide">36</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">18:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-37">
                        <td class="hide">37</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-38">
                        <td class="hide">38</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">19:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-39">
                        <td class="hide">39</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-40">
                        <td class="hide">40</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">20:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-41">
                        <td class="hide">41</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-42">
                        <td class="hide">42</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">21:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-43">
                        <td class="hide">43</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-44">
                        <td class="hide">44</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">22:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-45">
                        <td class="hide">45</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-46">
                        <td class="hide">46</td>
                        <!-- Every other row echo an hour block -->
                        <td class="time" rowspan="2">23:00</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-47">
                        <td class="hide">47</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="units-48">
                        <td class="hide">48</td>
                        <!-- start polling days -->
                        <!-- finish echo a row for each of the 48 units -->
                    </tr>                   


                </tbody>
            </table>
</div> <!-- end .main-col -->
    </div>
```

This is the JSON file from the radio1 directory, called schedule.php:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "testing", "test") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("radio1") or die("Could not select database");

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedule1");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"success":true,"error":"","data":{"schedule":['.json_encode($arr, $obj).']}}';
    ?>
```

The JSON displays well as *an individual file*, but I cannot emulate the effects seen at
[this site](http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=TFM) and [this website](http://www.tfmradio.com/on-air/station-schedule/). I'm trying to do this: [where the error message shows in the php / JSON](http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=) but have been having some trouble.

I've got part-way there, having managed to convert MySQL data into JSON.

I am using copyrighted material, but ***only for non-commercial, educational purposes*** and although I've got part of the way there with the JSON working to some degree (I can just about do basic json_encode).

How can I solve this effectively? All help will be appreciated.

I'm using both WAMP and MAMP, one machine with Windows 7, one with Mac OS X 10.6.8, this is a testing site.

I hope I've explained everything well enough for you, I have tried to learn this myself but want a bit of help.

Comment: So what is the specific problem you are having?

Comment: I cannot display the JSON in my PHP table.

Answer (score 1):

To report errors via json, you can add a function like this:

```
function reportError($message)
{
   die(json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'error'=>$message)));
}
```

then modify your code like this:

```
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "testing", "test") or reportError("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("radio1") or reportError("Could not select database");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mysql_fetch_assoc($rs) instead of mysql_fetch_object(), and in json_encode use only one param...

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedule1");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"success":true,"error":"","data":{"schedule":['.json_encode($arr).']}}';
```

Comment: By the way I don't know whats the use of the second param in json_encode... i always thought it was just options

Comment: The JSON isn't displaying the file, despite the fact I made the changes. This is index.php: http://pastebin.com/BpG0k5N2. @lascort, I made your changes, but it's not quite working yet...